# Monitoring elements in page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing Google Chrome Extension, which finds some elements in some web-site and changes them in some way (so much "some", hmm :-) ). These elements are not displayed when HTML is loaded and they're loaded in scripts of the page. Also, they can appear much later.

Currently I'm running checks every little time and ignore the elements, which are already processed:

```
var processed = [];

//...

function checkElements() {
    var elements = document.querySelectorAll(//...

    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i) {
        var element = elements[i];

        if (processed.indexOf(element) > -1) continue; // ignore processed elements
        processed.push(element);

        // process element
    }
}

setInterval(checkElements, TIMEOUT);
```

But that looks silly and it seems to me that performance is awful.

Can I create some trigger on creating/changing of elements? What is the idiomatic JS way for doing that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can. One way to do it is using [MutationObservers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).

> #### MutationObserver
>
> MutationObserver provides developers a way to react to changes in a DOM. It is designed as a replacement for Mutation Events defined in the DOM3 Events specification.

An example of how to do it taken from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver):

```
// select the target node
var target = document.querySelector('#some-id');

// create an observer instance
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
        console.log(mutation.type);
    });    
});

// configuration of the observer:
var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true };

// pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
observer.observe(target, config);

// later, you can stop observing
observer.disconnect();
```

Comment: Since the documentation states, that Mutation Observers are preferred and you answered earlies, I accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use "Mutations events" to listen changes on body DOM. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events

For example, if you want to listen when elements will be added to body:

```
var body = document.querySelector('body');
body.addEventListener("DOMNodeInserted", function (ev) {

}, false);
```

Comment: Mutation events are **deprecated**. In fact, this warning is on the top of the page you link to. Mutation Observers is the modern approach.

Comment: Thanks Xan, I read about "Mutation Observers" and it's the best approach.